# React component setting state isnt working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React newbie here, can someone please explain to me why this does not work:

**Problem**

Whenever the state is set, it removes the whole component from the page. I have isolated the issue to ensure this is only when the setAnimate is changed and it still has the same effect.

**Expected result**

I change the state when the user scrolls down to the section (which works as expected), when this state is changed, this should change the Animejs autoplay value to true to display the section (this bit is not working, currently it is removing the section from the page).

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Container } from '@material-ui/core';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import style from './section.module.scss';
import Anime from 'react-anime';

export const Section = ({children}) => {
    let sectionPosition;
    const [animaion, setAnimation] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    }, []);

    const handleScroll = () => {
        if (window.scrollY > sectionPosition.offsetTop) {
            setAnimation(true);
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        }
    };

    return (
        <Anime
            easing='linear'
            duration={500}
            autoplay={animaion}
            opacity={[0,1]}
            translateY={['100px', '0']}
        >
            <Container component="section" classes={{root: style.section}}>
                <div ref={el => sectionPosition = el}>
                    {children}
                </div>
            </Container>
        </Anime>
    );
};


Section.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

export default Section;
```

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: _"it removes the whole component from the page"_ Is an error being thrown in your javascript console when this happens?

Comment: No, no errors are being shown. Although console logging before the setstate working, whereas after it does not as it has already been removed.

Comment: Could you add some demo with component and it's problem on some sandbox? (like codesandbox)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the issue was with react-anime library. Removing this and writing the transition styling myself resolved the issue.

It doesnt appear that react-anime has an official way of dynamically playing the animation, as above i was using `autoplay` which doesnt seem to be the correct way of doing this.